# how to create dynamic multi dimensional string array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am using three tables, i need to use dynamic multi dimensional string array
to push the values from the tables

```
var i = 3    
var j;    
for(var j = 0; j < i.length; i++){    
var a =  ProjectContext.My_prj_project.Select(i => new 
        {                            
                            id = i.Prj_project_name_id            
        }).Count();

 var b = ProjectContext.My_prj_projects.Select(i => new
                        {
                            id = i.Prj_project_name_id
                        }).Count();

 var c = ProjectContext.My_prj_pro.Select(i => new
                        {
                            id = i.Prj_project_name_id    
                        }).Count();
}
```

From these tables the individual count value should be stored in string array 
dynamically, I am trying to use this syntax:

```
List<List<string>> twoDimensional = new List<List<string>>();
```

but its not working, so please anyone can can send that how can i solve this problem.

Comment: Your `i` variable is integer. What `i.length` means in your code? Also you don't use `j` variable in loop. What you are trying to select from database? And what *its not working* means? Do you get an error? What error?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> twoDimensional = new List<string>();
```

then

```
twoDimensional.add(a);
twoDimensional .add(b);
twoDimensional .add(c);
```